# tagging system using facebook friend list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My friend and I are working on an app that will use Facebook's friendlist.  We're trying to create a tagging system in which people can tag each other...similar to example in screenshot.

Does facebook provide this functionality out-of-box or do I have to create this sort of search/input field?  I wasn't sure if I simply have to style something they provide or if I have to make it.

[image: friend list search]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tag people on a just like that.

You have to use Open Graph concepts- [**Mention Tagging**](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/21/bringing-mention-tagging-to-open-graph/)

But if you want to post a **photo**, then you can tag the people using `tag` parameter.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for point me in a direction.  It's a beast navigating through all the FB documentation.